# Passing connection between two files - azure functions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a server.js file inside a connections folder that I'm trying to use and have all my azure functions reference so that it doesn't instantiate a connection after every API call. I'm having issues exporting the connection and importing it correctly in my azure functions. Is this not possible. If it is, what am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help!

server.js

```
const redis = require('redis');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient(6380, process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME + '.redis.cache.windows.net', {
  auth_pass: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY,
  tls: { servername: process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME + '.redis.cache.windows.net' }
});

module.exports = { client };
```

top of azure function file importing connection

```
const redis = require('redis');

var redisConnection = require("../connections/server")


console.log("THE CLIENT IS " + redisConnection.client.connected);
```

Error: `client is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have tested this on Azure portal. I created two http trigger functions named `HttpTrigger1` and `HttpTrigger2`.

**HttpTrigger1** function

[image]

**HttpTrigger2** function

[image]

It seems that your code is correct, please check your function project directory structure, mine is

[image]

You can test it locally, here are my code for your reference:

The **server.js** file

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient(6380, 'test.redis.cache.windows.net', 
        {auth_pass: 'XXXX=', tls: {servername: 'test.redis.cache.windows.net'}});

module.exports = { client };
```

The function code

```
const redis = require('redis');

var redisConnection = require("../connections/server")

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log("THE CLIENT IS " + redisConnection.client.connected);
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "THE CLIENT IS " + redisConnection.client.connected
    };

};
```